# How can I make cowsay to say server logging messages?

Tags: cowsay

I'm doing my thesis with Node-red on Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi will run only node-red, so I thought of spicing things up a bit for the Raspberry Pi terminal.

I'm already piping the Node-red output through lolcat, but I still feel like it could use something more... Something like a cow saying all those logs.

So the problem is that cowsay outputs only on the program exit. If I read one line in bash script and push it to cowsay, like in another question here, there's a new cow for every logging message. This would clutter the terminal with a horde of cows, which I like the sound of, but isn't really practical.

I feel like I'm pushing the limits of this being easier to do from scratch instead of using cowsay, but I'll ask anyway:
How do I have a single cow from cowsay saying the log messages, having the logs scroll upwards in the speech bubble without the cow moving?

Comment: You could try calling cowsay with enough blank lines in front of it so the cow always appears in the same spot.

Comment: True, thought of something like that. I'm just not sure how to save the screenful of log lines to be pushed to cowsay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of a terminal is to print output line by line. So having a fixed bottom part and a change in previous lines goes against this.

However you could simulate this with a terminal multiplexer (e.g. `tmux` or `screen`). They create split screen terminals. This way you can have e.g. the bottom 10% of the screen be one terminal where the cow is printed and left untouched. In the top 90% the actual action is happening and the lines scroll as expected.

Take a look at terminal multiplexers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/how-to-split-the-terminal-into-more-than-one-view).

Comment: Ah yes, terminal multiplexer. This certainly works. Any way to start this all up in a script? I've got the lolcat only version in post-boot script. Image of the test: https://imgur.com/a/9YfYEgO

Comment: Googled a bit and found the answer to my comment. Now my .bashrc has lines: `tmux new-session -d '<path/to/node-red + node-red user option> | <path/to/lolcat>'; tmux split-window -v -l 6 '<path/to/cowsay> - | <path/to/lolcat>; <path/to/cowsay>'; tmux -2 attach-session -d`. I don't think it's the cleanest lines of commands as I just copied some tmux commands without understanding everything, but it works.

Comment: @PuuKala : `tmux` allows for creating a config file that can be loaded with `-f <path-to-tmux.conf>`. This way your bashrc would be less crowded.